# TinyMCE wrong button names

Tags: javascript, tinymce

[image: Button naming problem]

The same thing is for all the buttons. Advanced theme. 
I tired trying to figure out what is going on here.

Editor init:

```
   tinyMCE.init({
     // General options
    elements : "elm1",  mode : "textareas",
theme : "advanced",
force_br_newlines : true,
theme_advanced_buttons1 : "link,unlink,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|",
theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
theme_advanced_buttons4 : "",
theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "",
theme_advanced_resizing : true,
    });
```

**UPD:** TinyMCE works with simple theme. Problem caused by advanced theme only.

Comment: can you post your full tinymce config?

Comment: posted in question description

Comment: there seems to be nothing wrong with your configuration. i created a tinymce fiddle and everything works fine: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/U2caab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to recreate your problem by deliberately introducing some errors in en.js.

So my suggestion is to have a fresh copy of en.js

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thanks. After replacement en.js with advanced theme's en.js finally got it to work!

Answer (score 1):

Translation JS file is missing. Probably you initiated tinyMCE in a wrong way.

Comment: Thanks for reply.
en.js is loaded correctly - I can view it through web developer console on Chrome

Comment: Try to run this on console, and see is issue resolved or not, If yes, then en.js is not loaded correctly, or has irrelevant content. `tinyMCE.addI18n('en.advanced', {"justifyfull_desc": "test"})`

Comment: the same thing after running that.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that themes/advanced/skins/cirkuit/ui.css is missing or is corrupt.  Try to check skins directory and look for the css files inside this directory.  If these css files are in place, you will not face this issue.

Comment: Thank you for answer.
There's no cirkuit/ folder. I connected 
/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/skins/default/ui.css
but the problem still exists

Comment: Please check if jquery.js, tiny_mce.js, online_editor.css, ui.css and window.css are added.

Comment: Checked. All the styles and js are in place

Comment: Try changing theme from advanced to simple.  Even then, if it doesn't work then it looks as if TinyMCE installation is incomplete or corrupt.  Try to reinstall it.

Comment: By the way, simple theme works perfect. It's only with advanced.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in incompatibility of language file formats